# Create instance of class in one ViewController and use this to display data in another

Tags: ios, swift, class, instance

I am trying to create an instance of a "budget" class when I click a button that for now just has the information on the inputed gross income. When this button is pressed I want to create an instance of this budget class and then use this instance in a new view controller that appears to display data. What is the best way to do this? Should I be doing this a different way?

Right now I have a budget class as shown below:

```
import Foundation

class Budget {
    private var _grossIncome: Int!

    var grossIncome: Int {
        return _grossIncome
    }

    init(grossIncome: Int) {
        self._grossIncome = grossIncome
    }
}
```

And a view controller with the button to be pressed here:

```
import UIKit

class CreateNewBudgetVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var grossIncomeVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var federalExptVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateExptVal: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var deductionsList: UITableView!

    @IBAction func cancelPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "CancelSegue", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func generateBudgetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "GenerateSegue", sender: self)
        let budget = Budget(grossIncome: Int(grossIncomeVal.text!)!)
    }
}
```

So, how do I make it so when the "genereateBudgetPressed" method is called on button click it creates a new instance of the budget class with the inputed gross income and I can use this information to display things on a new view controller? Is there a better way to be doing this whole process?

Comment: There is no reason for `_grossIncome` to be an `Int!`. It can just be an `Int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, would be to pass the budget instance as the sender to the `performSegue` call. That way, in prepare for segue, you can get that value out and populate the `segue.destination` viewcontroller.

```
@IBAction func generateBudgetPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let budget = Budget(grossIncome: Int(grossIncomeVal.text!)!)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "GenerateSegue", sender: budget)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let budget = sender as? Budget, let destination = segue.destination as? YourDestinationViewController {
        destination.budget = budget
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you, only question is what would the code in the new view controller be? I tried setting up an init() but it is giving me issues.

Comment: Well, if you are using storyboards, you generally don't override the init for UIViewControllers. I would declare the UIViewController class with a `var budget: Budget!` - this is an implicitly unwrapped optional, meaning that you don't have to check for nil, but in the case that the previous controller didn't provide a value in `prepare(for:sender:)`, it will crash your app. This is generally caught in development, but you should decide how you want to handle it - it could also be a normal optional like so: `var budget: Budget?`